# How to read a stream of json objects?

Tags: json.net

It seems that the serializer.Deserialize overloads can only read one thing from their input stream. In particular, I can't figure out how to read multiple objects of the kind "{...} {...} ..." incrementally.

After the first serializer.Deserialize call, all subsequent calls to the same stream throw an exception.

Since it's only the parser who knows when an object representation ends, it's only the parser who knows when the next one starts.

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON?  Have you considered wrapping all of your objects in an array?

Comment: @BrianRogers See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian asked, I do have control over the json, but I don't want to wrap it into an array as I want to read incrementally.

In this case, I found the solution to ask the serializer not to indent (the default) and seperate the objects by newline. This works because newlines are escaped when they occur in json string literals - so this is one character that, without indenting, cannot be part of the json proper and is thus suitable as a separation character.

Would still be cool if the library could do it - I'll accept all answers that are better and more general that this one.